# How to prevent a button from going to original state when refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I have a button `#first` which upon click is replaced with `#second`. After getting the second button and if I refresh the page I am going back to the first button. If I want my button to be the second button even after refresh how can I achieve this?
Thank in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
          $("#first").replaceWith('<button id="second">Second Button</button>');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="first">firstbutton</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use local storage and on window load just get the button state from there

Comment: You need to persist the state of the button to be stored externally of the page. Either sessionStorage, localStorage, cookies or the server via AJAX would work depending on what you require and have available.

Answer (score 2):

set a cookie to persist the state of button and on document.ready,fetch the saved state and display it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Use local storage and on window load just get the button state from there.

Example from : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

You could change this to :

```
      // Store
      localStorage.setItem("buttonState", "Second");
      // Retrieve
      var buttonState = localStorage.getItem("buttonState");
```

So in your case :

```
      var buttonState = localStorage.getItem("buttonState");   
      $(document).ready(function() { //on document ready
        if(buttonState){ //check if buttonState exists
            if(buttonState === 'Second'){ //if button state = second
              //logic to change state to second
              $("#first").replaceWith('<button id="second">Second Button</button>');
            }
    }
        $("button").click(function() {
          $("#first").replaceWith('<button id="second">Second Button</button>');
          localStorage.setItem("buttonState", "Second");
        });
        }
```

So in your example, if you change state to second, save the state like about (setItem) and then retrieve that on document ready or window load.

Here is an example fiddle of it working : https://jsfiddle.net/wg7xL4sa/2/

Notice I have commented out the localStorage.clear(). Use this to reset your local storage.

Comment: Or maybe to use the sessionStorage as an alternative

Comment: No its like it must be first button in the first sight but after changing its state to second('which upon click') it must remain in that state only even after refresh ...
https://jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/wg7xL4sa/ this is what i have done

Comment: You added more to the example i gave. You shouldn't set the button state at first. You only set it when you click the button. Here is your updated fiddle exactly as I did it : https://jsfiddle.net/wg7xL4sa/1/